# How can I find small resorts in Puerto Rico or the Dominican Republic?

Tags: caribbean, puerto-rico, resorts, dominican-republic

I'm trying to find a small, elegant resort in one of these places (or maybe elsewhere in the Caribbean, although these are the easiest to fly to from the US), but I'm having a hard time. The only places I can find are very large resorts with golf, casinos, marinas, and all kinds of other facilities I don't need or want.

I really just want seclusion, beach, restaurants, and a little luxury, but I cannot find such a thing anywhere. Can anyone recommend a method of finding one?

Comment: Voting to leave open. Joshua isn't asking us to plan his itinerary for him.

Comment: You might search using the word *boutique* with either resorts or hotels, which should [return results similar to this](https://www.oyster.com/caribbean/hotels/roundups/best-boutique-all-inclusive-resorts-in-the-caribbean/)

Comment: Four Seasons !!

Answer (score 1):

When looking for hotels in specific areas I like using google maps.  I just look around and click around.  I use both the street view and satellite view help to judge the size and the quality of the place.

It may take a little bit longer, but it's fun and kind of feels like your already on on a little pre-vacation.